# How can I loop through this array?

Tags: php

I have an array from a database that I'd like to loop through and where the item_id is the same, add the qty(quantity) to get a total quantity. I've tried using a while loop to into the inner arrays with a maximum count determined by count(outer array) and this hasn't presented me with a desired outcome.

Here's the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [lpo_id] => 20
            [invoice_no] => 1483958702
            [external_invoice_no] => 1
            [item_id] => 21
            [qty] => 14
            [currency] => USD
            [price] => 1.31
            [date] => 1483909200
            [supplier_id] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [lpo_id] => 20
            [invoice_no] => 1483958702
            [external_invoice_no] => 1
            [item_id] => 22
            [qty] => 15
            [currency] => USD
            [price] => 2.52
            [date] => 1483909200
            [supplier_id] => 9
        )

)
```

Here's the DB query:

```
public function getSupplierInvoiceByRefNo($ourRef) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->_table_20}` WHERE `invoice_no` = '$ourRef'";
  return $this->db->fetchAll($sql);
}

public function fetchAll($sql) {
    $result = $this->query($sql);
    $out = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $out[] = $row;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    return $out;
}
```

DB Table:

```
id | lpo_id | invoice_no | external_invoice_no | item_id | qty | currency | price | date | supplier_id
```

Desired output is to have the following table where line items with same item_id have a totaled qty and are displayed only once in the output table

```
item_id | qty | price | currency
```

Comment: Unable to get your question what is your desired output?

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see your php code you said you tried. How do you expect us to help with it if you do not post it?

Comment: And why should `list()` not be available in php versions lower than 7?

Comment: I would say you could do this quicker and more simply by changing the query you run on the database to do this all for you. Post your query. Always try to fix the source of the error, Fiddling rubbish into good data is a bad practice

Comment: `$final_sum = array();

foreach ($array as $arr){
  $final_sum[$arr['item_id']] = $final_sum[$arr['item_id']]+$arr['qty']];
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_sum);`

Comment: andromeda please check the comments and answers. Mark+up-vote one answer as accepted which works for you.You can up-vote others too if they are useful.Thanks

Comment: @Anant I was working on the clarifications which are up.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have posted the query and db structure. Kindly take a look

Comment: I dont see a `units` column in the table??

Comment: I need the item_id, qty, units, price, currency for this particular output but others columns may be useful too. the main problem is summing the qty and associating that with an item_id then looping through it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly if I have the item_id, getting units is simply a method call. I'll remove it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should produce what you are after

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(qty) as qty, price, currency 
FROM `{$this->_table_20}` 
WHERE `invoice_no` = '$ourRef'
GROUP BY item_id";
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code:

```
foreach($arrays as $a) 
{
   foreach ($a as $key => $value) 
       echo $key . '=' . $value;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Would be simpler to FIX the query to do the selection correctly

Answer (score 2):

***I think you want like this:-***

```
$final_sum = array();

foreach ($array as $arr){
  $final_sum[$arr['item_id']] += $arr['qty']];
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_sum); // will give you an array of keys = item_id and values = sum of those id's quantities from original array
```

***Note:- It will be really easy if you do it through query by using `SUM()` as suggested by `@RiggsFolly`***

Comment: Would be simpler to FIX the query to do the selection correctly

Comment: @RiggsFolly  aggreed

Comment: I would also prefer a query alternative if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
$data = array(
array('id'=>1,'item_id'=>2,'qty'=>13),
array('id'=>2,'item_id'=>3,'qty'=>16),
array('id'=>3,'item_id'=>2,'qty'=>33),
array('id'=>3,'item_id'=>3,'qty'=>43),
array('id'=>3,'item_id'=>4,'qty'=>30));

$new = array();
foreach($data as $value){
if($new[$value['item_id']]){
    $new[$value['item_id']]+= $value[qty];
}else{
  $new[$value['item_id']] = $value['qty'];
}

}echo "<pre>";print_r($new);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [2] => 46
    [3] => 59
    [4] => 30
)
```

Comment: Would be simpler to FIX the query to do the selection correctly